# Django search "DoesNotExist"

Tags: python, django, search, django-queryset

I'm using Django to build a website for a football club, which contains many blog articles. I'm trying to include a search bar, but I can't make it work. When submitting the search term, the following error is shown:

> DoesNotExist at /web/search/
>   Articulo matching query does not exist.

Here is my code:

## views.py

```
def search(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q', '')
    if query:
        try:
            qset = (
                    Articulo(titulo__icontains=query) |
                    Articulo(cuerpo_icontains=query)
            )
            results = Articulo.objects.filter(qset).distinct()
        except Articulo.DoesNotExist:
            results = None
    else:
        results = []
    return render_to_response('web/buscar.html', {"results": results, "query": query})
```

## index.html

```
<div id="busqueda" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <span id="cruz" class="fas fa-times fa-2x"></span>
        <form method="GET" action="/web/search/" class="form my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input id="searchBox" value="{{ query|escape }}" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Buscar" aria-label="Buscar">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Buscar</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

## urls.py

```
url(r'^search/$', search),
```

## models.py

```
class Articulo(models.Model):
    """Un artículo de la página"""
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, default="")
    CATEGORIAS = (
        ('Primera y Sub 21', 'Primera y Sub 21'),
        ('Inferiores', 'Inferiores'),
        ('Básquet', 'Básquet'),
        ('Hockey', 'Hockey'),
        ('Gurises', 'Gurises'),
        ('Generales', 'Generales'),
        ('Institucionales', 'Institucionales'),
        ('Senior', 'Senior'),
    )
    categoria = models.CharField(
        max_length=200,
        choices=CATEGORIAS
    )
    cuerpo = RichTextField()
    fecha_hora= models.DateTimeField()
    foto = models.ImageField()
    url_video = models.CharField(help_text='Url del video de facebook (opcional). Para obtener el link, ir al video, apretar donde están los 3 puntitos y poner "insertar". Pegar aquí solo el link del video, borrar el resto. Ejemplo: https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FJuanCruzPiornoOficial%2Fvideos%2F302760100205413', max_length=500,blank=True)
    album_flickr = models.CharField(help_text="Subir fotos a Flickr, crear un álbum, compartirlo eligiendo la opción 'Insertar', elegir el tamaño más grande, y pegar el link aquí", max_length=700, blank=True)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.titulo)

        super(Articulo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titulo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are trying to perform a "search" (or filtering) you should use "fitler()" instead of get(), it makes more sense semantically. For your information, filter does not raise an exception if the result is empty.
Your code will look similar to:

```
from django.db.models import Q

def search(request):
    results = []
    query = request.GET.get('q', '')
    if query:
        qset = Q(titulo__icontains=query) | Q(cuerpo__icontains=query)
        results = Articulo.objects.filter(qset).distinct()

    ctx = {"results": results, "query": query}
    return render_to_response('web/buscar.html', ctx)
```

If you are getting `DoesNotExist` exceptions with code which uses `filter()` you should take a look to the traceback to look for the li`urls.py` file to ensure that your desired views is being called and not other one.

Comment: Thanks! The problem was in my urls.py file. Thanks to you, I was able to solve it!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
def search(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q', '')
    if query:
        try:
            qset = Articulo.objects.filter(Q(titulo__icontains=query) | cuerpo_icontains = query)  # change is here <<
            results = Articulo.objects.filter(some_field=some_value).distinct() # change is here <<
        except Articulo.DoesNotExist:
            results = None
    else:
        results = []
    return render_to_response('web/buscar.html', {"results": results, "query": query})
```

Note: I'm not sure why you are using `qset` and `result` there!

Answer (score 0):

first you need to import Q after that you can lookup function that takes keyword-arguments (e.g. filter(), exclude(), get()

```
from django.db.models import Q
def search(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q', '')
    if query:
        Articulo.objects.get(
            Q(titulo__icontains=query) |
            Q(cuerpo_icontains=query)
           )
    return query
```

for more info you can check the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I tried this and didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db.models import Q

def search(request):
    results = []
    query = request.GET.get('q', None)
    if query:
       try:
        results = Articulo.objects.filter(Q(titulo__icontains=query) | Q(cuerpo_icontains=query))
       except Articulo.DoesNotExist:
           pass
    return render_to_response('web/buscar.html',{"results": results, "query": query})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried this but the error remains :(